How to integrate view factor over surface of triangle?
Given a point $P$ in the xy-plane and a triangle $\Delta$ with vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$, I am trying to simplify the function:
$$B(P)=\iint_\Delta\phi(Q)\frac{\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2}{\pi r^2}\,dA $$
Where:

$\theta_1$ is the angle between segment $PQ$ and the normal of the xy-plane,
$\theta_2$ is the angle between segment $PQ$ and the normal of the triangle,
$r$ is the distance between $P$ and $Q$.

In crude words, this is integrating the function $\phi$ weighted by the view factor between the point $Q\in\Delta$ and the given point $P$.
I'm trying to use this for a shader, where $\phi$ is encoding some image in the surface of $\Delta$. The shader will then find the value of $B$ for some points in the xy-plane. That means that $\phi$ is only known at execution time, but can be differentiated and integrated using discrete methods. (I think)
I started my attempt by defining the vectors:
$$v(s,t)=sA+tB+(1-s-t)C\\u(x,y)=(x,y,0)$$
Where $v$ is parameterizing $\Delta$ over $s\in[0,1]$, $t\in[0,1-s]$. I can then find that:
$$\cos\theta_1=\frac{\hat k\cdot(v-u)}{\left\|v-u\right\|}=\frac{\hat k\cdot v}{\left\|v-u\right\|}\\\cos\theta_2=\frac{n\cdot(v-u)}{\left\|v-u\right\|}=\frac{n\cdot u}{\left\|v-u\right\|}$$
Then, rewriting the integral using vectors, I got:
$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-s}\phi(s,t)\frac{(\hat k\cdot v)(n\cdot u)}{\pi\left\|v-u\right\|^4}\left\|\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right\|\,dt\,ds$$
And now I don't know how to continue. I think what's causing most of the trouble is this norm in the denominator. Maybe there is a better way to parameterize the triangle. I don't know.
For my needs, I would still be happy to find a numerical solution that doesn't require iterating over the points of $\Delta$.
I admit that I didn't pay much attention to calculus classes when I was in university. That's why I'm here asking for you help. Thanks in advance.
